# datepicker not entering a valid value in Safari or Chrome

Tags: forms, date, google-chrome, safari, picker

I am going through a Wordpress Course and have a registration form with a date picker using the jQuery date picker. The input type is datetime-local. The placeholder is Date. This was working a week ago but now its not and I can't find a reason for it not to be working. On Safari, I see today's date in the placeholder and the calendar works and will change the date and time. Chrome shows the MM-DD-YYYY format and the calendar icon. That calendar works as well. But when I submit the from, it wants me to enter a valid value. If I manually enter the information without the date picker, it works. If enter a value manually after trying the date picker, it will not work.

On Safari, I see today's date in the placeholder and I would click on the calendar and change the date and time. Same thing on Chrome. But when I submit the from, it wants me to enter a valid value. If I manually enter the information without the date picker, it works. If enter a value manually after trying the date picker, it will not work. When this was working originally, the course wanted made to add the datetime pollyfill JS which I did and everything seemed to still work. Earlier today I removed that JS. It worked earlier. I took a break and then when I reopened Safari, the issue started happening again. I can't figure out why it would say it's invalid. I am running on a Mac with MacOs 12.6.7 with Safari 16.5.1 and Chrome Version 114.0.5735.198.
Here is my form code.

```
<form class="reservation-form" method="post">
                    <h2>Make a reservation</h2>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="datetime-local" name="date" placeholder="Date" step="300" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-Mail" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" placeholder="Phone Number" required>
                    </div>

                    <div class="field">
                        <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" name="reservation" class="button" value="Send">

                    <input type="hidden" name="hidden" value="1">
                </form>
```

Thank you.